# Make use of google calendar into my website?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have a website that has some register users, now I want to provide calendar service for them. I am considering using google calendar to ease my development work, the requirement should be:

1) Google calendar needs to support non google users, because my website users are not google users
2) Support provision from my website, that means my website can create calendar account for my users.
...

For simplicity, my objective is create one account for all the registered users, and manupulate the data in the calendar on behave of my user.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [Google Apps for Business](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/features.html), which has a [provisioning API](http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/gdata_provisioning_api_v2.0_reference.html).

Comment: Is it possible to have a single user with multiple hidden calendars and load the appropiate calendar for each user?  Seems feasible with Google Calendar, but I have a lot of doubts about how to render and interact with it in the client side.